# Getting a very unusual error to me, I am new to programming keep in mind

Tags: c#

```
namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student Student = new Student();
            int quit;
            quit = 0;
            string choice;
            choice = "";
            string firstName;
            firstName = "";
            string lastName;
            lastName = "";
            int phoneNumber;
            phoneNumber = 0;

            while (quit != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A) Display student if student exists");
                Console.WriteLine("B) Add a new Student");
                Console.WriteLine("C) Add Phone Number");
                Console.WriteLine("D) Exit program");

                Console.WriteLine("Menu Option:");
                try
                {
                    choice = (Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch(FormatException )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Format");
                }
                catch(OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Number is too large ");
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Something Happened");
                }

                if (choice == "D"|| choice == "d")
                {
                    quit = 1;
                }
                else if(choice == "A"|| choice == "a")
                {
                    Student.DisplayStudent();
                }
                else if(choice == "B"|| choice =="b")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("First Name:");
                    firstName = Console.ReadLine();

                    while(firstName == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: No name entered, try again");
                        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Last Name:");
                    lastName = Console.ReadLine();

                    while (lastName == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: No name entered, try again");
                        lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone Number:");
                    try
                    {
                        phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: No phone number entered, try again");
                        phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }

                    while (phoneNumber < 0.00)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: Positive Integers Only");
                        phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    Student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
                }
                else if(choice == "C"|| choice =="c")
                {
                    if (firstName == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: No student exists, add a student");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Student.DisplayStudent();
                        Console.WriteLine("First name:");
                        Student =Console.ReadLine(); //where I am getting an error

                        while (firstName == "")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: No first name entered, try again");
                            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Last name:");
                        lastName = Console.ReadLine();

                        while (lastName == "")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: No last name entered, try again");
                            lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number:");
                        try
                        {
                            phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            Student.EditStudent();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: No phone number entered, try again");
                            phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }

                        while (phoneNumber < 0.00)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: Negative phone number value entered, try again");
                            phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }          
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private int phoneNumber;

        public Student()
        {
            firstName = "";
            lastName = "";
            phoneNumber = 0;
        }

        public Student(string firstName, string lastName, int phoneNumber)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public void DisplayStudent()
        {
            if (firstName == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: No first name exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First name is: {0}", firstName);
                Console.WriteLine("Last name is: {0}", lastName);
                Console.WriteLine("Phone number is:{0}", phoneNumber.ToString("C"));
            }
        }

        public void EditStudent()
        {
            string Student;
            Student = "";

            if (Student == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: No student exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(firstName);
                Console.WriteLine(lastName);
                Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber.ToString("C"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I used one of my old programs and just re-visioned it into this new project, renamed variables and things as such, I am getting a weird error

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Assignment_4.Student'

I have tried parsing it to know avail and researched this high and low, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please narrow down the problem. Indicate which line has the problem. Try and see if you can fix it. Think about your variable and type names, don't get them mixed up.(And please don't expect us to do your homework ....)

Comment: `Student =Console.ReadLine();` -- what, _exactly_, did you expect this statement to do? It obviously cannot work; the `ReadLine()` method returns a `string` object, not a `Student` object. But presumably you'd like a better answer than just "nope, that doesn't work". What _do_ you want the line to do?

Comment: I coded it this far, I wrote the comment beside where my problem is

Comment: @Peter Duniho I think you need to understand that this guy is a newbie. Just respect whatever code he has written so far.

Comment: Sorry to all who were upset over my question, I am banned from asking more now, I didn't know you couldn't be a beginner programmer to post here

Comment: @LeGreen95, sorry if everyone jumped on you. You are welcome -- and encouraged -- to be a beginner. But be an inquisitive beginner, think about how to help others help you. Try to keep your question concise and narrow in on the problem -- doing so will also help you improve your own debugging skills. And review the StackExchange guidelines, see the "Tour" option on the "help" drop-down in the upper right. Ask better questions, and you will get better answers. Good luck. And welcome. No, really. :-)

Comment: It's all good, I will just learn to be careful what to ask in the programming field

Comment: You didn't get banned because of the question. You got banned (temporarily) because of the downvotes, and you got the downvotes because you posted a question without following the guidelines provided in the tutorial and help of StackOverflow. IMHO, two of the most important articles to read are http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; your question fails in a number of ways to adhere to the suggestions offered there. You can't just dump your code to the site and hope for the best; you're expected to put some effort into writing a good, useful question.

Comment: I didn't know writing all that code was "no effort" and explaining my issue was "no effort"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Student =Console.ReadLine(); //where I am getting an error
```

fails because Console.ReadLine() returns a string, but you are attempting to assign it to a variable of type Student (the variable is confusingly also called Student).

There is no way for the compiler to convert a string to the type Student.

It looks like you intend that line to be

```
firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

based on the structure of the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement from `Student =Console.ReadLine();` to `Student.firstName =Console.ReadLine();`.
Alternatively, you can do

```
firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```